# Ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

я понимаю, возможно это легкая ошибка. Но уже большое кол-во времени не могу её решить.

Есть таблица с кнопкой удалить в каждой записи таблицы, при нажатии на кнопку должен отправляться ajax-запрос, но это вызывает ошибку.

Кнопка вызова функции

```
<td data-label="Remove">
            <a href="#" onclick="removeItemFromCart('Клик!')" data-line="0" data-id="6154534944950" class="cart__remove icon icon-x text-right large--text-center"></a>
          </td>
```

ajax

```
<!--AJAX request-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function removeItemFromCart(id) {
            alert(id)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Получаю -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот есть [пересекающийся вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055767/why-can-i-not-define-functions-in-jquerys-document-ready) у соседей. Как и в этом вопросе, тоже интересно почему нужен ready в данной ситуации? ready призван исполнять какой-то код исключительно после загрузки DOM. Но зачем нужно в нём объявлять функции?